# create regex with regex and text

Tags: python, regex

I wish match some  line in Cisco configuration based on the destination.
To make some test I made the following:

```
acl = 'ip route 10.5.48.0 255.255.255.0 10.242.245.65'
firewall = '10.242.245.65'
ip = r"(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)"
ip_route = (f"ip route {ip} {ip} {firewall}")

if re.search(ip_route, acl):
    print(acl)
```

No result.
I guess the problem is withe the variable `ip_route`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the anchors `^` and `$` in `ip`:

```
acl = 'ip route 10.5.48.0 255.255.255.0 10.242.245.65'
firewall = '10\.242\.245\.65'

# ip = r"(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)"
#         ^                                  ^ there is your problem
# Should be:
ip = r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"

ip_route = (f"ip route {ip} {ip} {firewall}")

if re.search(ip_route, acl):
    print(acl)
```

Those anchors assert beginning and end of the string respectively; you are using them in the middle of your constructed match.

Also (but not affecting this match) you should escape the `.` in `firewall` -- otherwise that regex metacharacter matches any character -- not just a dot.

Answer (score 0):

The `ip` regex contains `^` and `$`, which mean beginning and end of string.

But then `ip` is inserted in the middle of `ip_route` which is then used in `re.search`.

So you search for "something, beginning of string, something, end of string, something", which doesn't match `acl` because it doesn't contain "beginning of string" and "end of string" in the middle.

So: remove `^` and `$` from `ip`.